# How to check if service is enabled with launchd

Tags: macos, launchd

I can't figure out how to check from within C/C++ if a service is enabled via launchd.  I know I can use launchctl from the command line and am currently executing ' launchctl list myServiceName ' from fork/exec.

I've found that boostrap_look_up() might be the way to check this but I can't find enough documentation to condense this down to a simple example.

Can you shed light on this?  All I need is a small function to test if my service is actually registered and available.

Comment: Why are you not using launchctl list?

Comment: As I said in the first paragraph, I am using launchctl list from within fork/exec.  I want to avoid forking off any processes and make a function call.

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm not being clear.  I don't want to create a separate thread or process whether it's from pthreads or fork/exec or some other method.  I'm looking for a function call solution.  I know it exists I just can't find the right documentation.  Using the 'launchctl' application is not what I want to do.  My reasons are that for this application we are trying to eliminate any and all instances of secondary process creation.  It's a security application and I don't want to have to rely on executing anything from a shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has open sourced `launchd` and the source code is available at http://opensource.apple.com/source/launchd/launchd-442.26.2/

The source code for `launchctl` is in [support/launchctl.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/launchd/launchd-442.26.2/support/launchctl.c).  Hopefully you should be able to find what you need in there.  I suspect you need to look at the `list_cmd` function about two thirds of the way down the file.

If the answer isn't in `launchctl.c` then I really don't know where else it would be.

---

Initially I started looking for symbols in the `launchctl` binary.

The `bootstrap_look_up()` function you mention appears to be defined in `launchd/liblaunch/libbootstrap.c`.

Running `nm /bin/launchctl` provides a number of interesting symbols:

```
             ...
             U _bootstrap_get_root
             U _bootstrap_info
             U _bootstrap_look_up_per_user
             U _bootstrap_lookup_children
             U _bootstrap_parent
             U _bootstrap_port
             ...
             U _launch_data_alloc
             U _launch_data_array_get_count
             U _launch_data_array_get_index
             U _launch_data_array_set_index
             U _launch_data_copy
             U _launch_data_dict_insert
             U _launch_data_dict_iterate
             U _launch_data_dict_lookup
             U _launch_data_dict_remove
             U _launch_data_free
             U _launch_data_get_bool
             U _launch_data_get_errno
             U _launch_data_get_fd
             U _launch_data_get_integer
             U _launch_data_get_machport
             U _launch_data_get_opaque
             U _launch_data_get_opaque_size
             U _launch_data_get_real
             U _launch_data_get_string
             U _launch_data_get_type
             U _launch_data_new_bool
             U _launch_data_new_fd
             U _launch_data_new_opaque
             U _launch_data_new_string
             U _launch_data_set_bool
             U _launch_data_set_integer
             U _launch_data_set_opaque
             U _launch_data_set_real
             U _launch_data_set_string
             U _launch_msg
             ...
```

These `launch_data_` functions appear to be declared in `launchd/launch/liblaunch.c`.

As far as I can tell `liblaunch` is not installed as a system library and `libSystem` doesn't appear to contain these symbols either (just `bootstrap_init` is exported).

I would suggest downloading the `launchd` source, compiling your own `liblaunch` and seeing if you can get the functionality you require by linking it to your project.  I have no idea if this will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It will take me some time to find out if I can get something to work but I like your answer enough to accept it.  You've given me a lead where I had none before.